# Get all repos from an org with a keyword

Tags: python, github-api

I am trying to figure out the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get all repos from a particular organization that has one search term as a criteria. I can't seem to find the right combination. The Github API docs don't show how to combine your search. I have 2 problems so far. One, is I can't get a full list to show. Two, I don't know how to search within an org for all repos with a specific keyword. Like if I wanted to search in the org [Azure](https://github.com/Azure?q=cognitive&type=&language=) and find all repos that have the word "cognitive" in the repo name or description (searching in repo name and description is default, so no need to specify those). How would I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
import requests   

org = 'Azure'
response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos')
print(response.json())
```

But when I run that, it only returns about 30 repos. I am guessing it does not display them all (since there are thousands) but if I add a search criteria, the word "cognitive", this should cut the number of repos down by a lot, so that code I have so far, might only be missing the search criteria keyword. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like combining different search qualifiers did the trick. This code searches through organizations on Github, so that I only get results back for the repos that have the word "cognitive" in either the name of the repo or the description of it.

Below is the working code, you just replace the `{org}` and `org` with a Github organization of your choice. The code gets the URL of the JSON result (also called an html_url), then prints the URLs. Uncomment the `json.dumps()` function to get the full response.
NOTE: the space in `cognitive in:name,description` is OK to have.

**Code:**

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=cognitive in:name,description+org:{org}&per_page=100")
#print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
    
urls = []
for repo in response.json()['items']:
    urls.append(repo['html_url'])
    
print(len(urls), 'repos in the', org, 'organization.')
for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

**The pages of the Github API that helped put this together:**

This shows the basics of a repository search:
https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories

Shows you which qualifiers you want to use:
https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories

As Rishav mentioned, the Pagination part `per_page=100` returns the right number of results you need:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

All possible endpoints to get information with the API:
https://api.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because Github limit 30 items by default. If you want more consider pagination.

More here. [Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).

For Search Queries have a look at [Constructing a search query](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#constructing-a-search-query).

and also [Searching on GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-on-github).

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helps with that problem, but the main one is how do I search the Azure org of repos with the keyword "cognitive"?

Comment: Those are links, but not the answer. If you could help me figure out the exact answer, it would be complete. So far, I have this: `https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos?q=cognitive+in:readme` but it's not working. It seems to ignore the query and just returns all repos in "Azuer" org. Any ideas? Thanks.